# Jquery select elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by coma

Tags: jquery

Hi I am planing for a field level access using jquery. The logic is that all the fields should be disabled and only the fields with an attribute of editable_by should be Enabled.
editable_by is a coma seperated string, Please provide your insight on to this functionality

```
var user_group='3';
var user_role='lvl2';        
$(':input').attr("disabled","disabled");      
$('input[editable_by~="'+user_group+'"]').removeAttr("disabled");
.
.
.
.
.
<input type="text" editable_by="1,2,3" id="ReOrderLevel" value="3">
<input type="button" editable_by="lvl2"  id="btnUpdateReorderableStatus" value="Update Reorderable Status">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the "," (commas)... so

```
    var user_group = "1,2,3".split(',');
    $('input[editable_by=' + user_group.join('\\,') + ']').prop('disabled', false);
```

I might have misunderstood you.. if you are just looking to match "somepart" of the editable by.. then.

```
    var user_group = "3"
    $('input[editable_by*=' + user_group + ']').prop('disabled', false);
```